# Git pull from another repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository, dvcs

I have a repository called `Generic`, which is a generic application. I have forked it into a repository called `Acme`, which just builds upon the application stored `Generic` repository and adds Acme Co branding to it.

If I make changes to the core functionality in `Generic`, I want to update the `Acme` repository with the latest changes I have made to the core functionality in `Generic`. How would I do that?

As far as I can tell, I am essentially trying to merge the changes made in an upstream repository into the current fork.

If it means anything, I'm trying to do this because I have a generic application that I then build upon and brand for individual clients (like `Acme` in this example). If there is a cleaner way of doing this, let me know.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Issue the following command in your `Acme` repo. It adds a new remote repository named `upstream` that points to the `Generic` repo.

```
git remote add upstream https://location/of/generic.git
```

You can then merge any changes made to `Generic` into the current branch in `Acme` with the following command:

```
git pull upstream
```

If you just want it to download the changes without automatically merging, use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`.

If you want to disable pushing to that repository, set the push URL to an invalid URL using something like

```
git config remote.upstream.pushurl "NEVER GONNA GIVE YOU UP"
```

Git will now yell at you about not being able to find a repo if you try to push to `upstream` (and sorry about the Rickroll, but it was the first random string that popped into my head).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Just one other thing: is there a way I can make this remote read-only, so I don't end up accidentally pushing to it?

Comment: I started to answer but I see McLovin already edited his answer to include that.

Comment: Since git 2.9, you will need to specify the --allow-unrelated-histories flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/3799847

Comment: I needed to issue `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories upstream master`

Comment: I tried that but `git pull upstream` just hangs...  any ideas?

Comment: What if I want to push only to `Acme` and never to `Generic`?

Comment: For anybody looking to do this for dependencies, and not just build off of a project, see submodules: (http://blog.joncairns.com/2011/10/how-to-use-git-submodules/)

Comment: I would like to add one thing if there are several branches in upstream you have to mention the branch name from where you want to pull from.
    "git pull upstream <branchName>"

Answer (score 44):

In order to pull a particular branch from different repo you can use the below git command.

```
git pull <git_url> <branch> --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: Shame it isn't possible to pull a specific commit (so like doing a cherry pick from a different repo, which could be useful if you have used another repo as a base and you want to continue updating from the base repo). Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 7):

As [@vin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210870/191246) mentioned you can **`git pull`** directly from another repo without adding a new origin (assuming a pull from another repo's `master` branch to the local `master` branch):

```bash
git pull https://some-other-repo.git master:master

# OR pull to a new local branch
git pull https://some-other-repo.git master:new_local_branch
```

If the commit histories of the two repos are not linked then `--allow-unrelated-histories` will be needed but use it with caution, as it implies you know what you are doing.

You can also **`git push`** a local repo to another repo *without* adding it as a remote:

```bash
git push https://some-other-repo.git master:master

# OR create a new branch on remote
git push https://some-other-repo.git master:new_remote_branch
```