# How can I pull a single file from an external repository into my current project?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to pull a specific `.gitignore` from an external repository into my current project?

In this instance I would like to pull the Python `.gitignore` file from [this Github repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) but can't seem to find a way to do it.

If possible, I imagine this would be a very useful thing to learn for future projects.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're going specifically to GitHub for one specific file, there's a GitHub-specific way to do this directly. You used the `[git]` tag instead of the `[github]` tag, though, so see [Saurabh P Bhandari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331264/1256452).

Comment: This instance relates directly to GitHub but the question relates to git in general; how can this be achieved "the Github way"? `[github]` tag added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current project, run the following commands :

```
# Add external repo as remote (named "upstream")
git remote add upstream https://github.com/github/gitignore.git
#                       ^         <external repo url>         ^

# Fetch the external repo
git fetch upstream

# Checkout the particular file from the remote repo
git checkout upstream/master -- Python.gitignore
#           <remote>/<branch>    <path/to/file>  

# Commit the changes in your local repo
git commit
```

References :

- [How to pull a single file from a server repository in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28375418/10155936)
- [Git pull from another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24815952/10155936)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub specific method (perhaps better as a separate question, but see the see-also reference below):

If you click on [your own link](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) and look at the right side of the displayed-file-content pane, you will see a row of clickable boxes labeled <kbd>raw</kbd>, <kbd>blame</kbd>, and <kbd>history</kbd> (followed by clickable icons).  Clicking on the one labeled RAW gets you the URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore.

See also [What do raw.githubusercontent.com URLs represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39065921/1256452)